# Merging different size, different order table

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I'm a beginner in Mathematica, so this may be a simple request. I have generated some columns of names and data. I want to merge them into a single list of names, with a column for each attribute.

However, not all names are in each list, and I have had some problems ordering by the "Name" column.

Here are the lists

```
{
 {"Name", "Friend BC"},
 {"Bru-2", 25.1333},
 {"Al-1", 34.5667},
 {"Dave-4", 0.},
 {"Hal-8", 1.33333},
 {"Leo-12", 7.06667},
 {"Pat-16", 1.33333},
 {"Ned-14", 1.18333},
 {"Chas-3", 4.83333},
 {"Sam-19", 1.18333},
 {"Ed-5", 61.6667},
 {"Ian-9", 4.2},
 {"Ken-11", 1.7},
 {"Quinn-17", 0.733333},
 {"Unwin-21", 0.733333},
 {"Frank-6", 33.1333},
 {"Gra-7", 0.},
 {"Jo-10", 44.2833},
 {"Tom-20", 0.},
 {"Mal-13", 0.},
 {"Ollie-15", 35.9167}
}


{
 {"Name", "Advice BC"},
 {"Sam-19", 0.},
 {"Mal-13", 0.},
 {"Leo-12", 0.},
 {"Ian-9", 0.},
 {"Pat-16", 0.},
 {"Dave-4", 0.},
 {"Tom-20", 0.0769231},
 {"Quinn-17", 0.0769231},
 {"Ned-14", 0.0769231},
 {"Ken-11", 0.0769231},
 {"Jo-10", 0.0769231},
 {"Gra-7", 0.0769231},
 {"Frank-6", 0.0769231},
 {"Unwin-21", 0.0769231},
 {"Ron-18", 0.0769231},
 {"Hal-8", 0.0769231},
 {"Bru-2", 0.0769231},
 {"Al-1", 5.74359},
 {"Ed-5", 38.5},
 {"Chas-3", 38.5},
 {"Ollie-15", 70.4103}
}
```

I want the final table to be

```
{
 {"Name", "Advice BC","Friend BC"},
 {"Sam-19", 0., 1.18333},
 {"Mal-13", 0., 0.},
 {"Leo-12", 0., 7.06667},
 {"Ian-9", 0., 4.2},
 {"Pat-16", 0., 1.3333},
 {"Dave-4", 0., 0.},
 {"Tom-20", 0.0769231, 0.},
 {"Quinn-17", 0.0769231, 0.73333},
 {"Ned-14", 0.0769231, 1.18333},
 {"Ken-11", 0.0769231, 1.7},
 {"Jo-10", 0.0769231, 44.2833},
 {"Gra-7", 0.0769231, 0.},
 {"Frank-6", 0.0769231, 33.1333},
 {"Unwin-21", 0.0769231, 0.73333},
 {"Ron-18", 0.0769231, 0.},
 {"Hal-8", 0.0769231, 1.3333},
 {"Bru-2", 0.0769231, 25.1333},
 {"Al-1", 5.74359, 34.5667},
 {"Ed-5", 38.5, 61.6667},
 {"Chas-3", 38.5, 4.8333},
 {"Ollie-15", 70.4103, 35.9167},
 {"Sam-19", 0., NULL}
}
```

Any ideas? I can't seem to find any solutions already out there.

Also, how can I sort by the first column alphabetically?

Comment: In your desired output, "Sam-19" has values `0.` and `Null`, but each input table has a value for "Sam-19" is that correct?

Comment: You're right.  The Friend BC table was not meant to have Same-19.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you load your tables into T1 and T2, then you can solve this partially by converting each table to a list of rules, then finding all unique names across the two tables, and using replacement `/.` to insert only where a rule exists. This will leave blank fields just restating the name rather then giving Null. If you need the Null, you can add a rule for `_String->Null` which will pick these missed entries up:

```
 allnames = Union[T1[[2 ;;, 1]], T2[[2 ;;, 1]]];
 {allnames, allnames /. Rule @@@ Rest@T1, 
   allnames /. Rule @@@ Rest@T2} // Transpose // 
   Prepend[#, {"Name", "Advice BC", "Friend BC"}] & // Grid
```

Also if you need to sort by the first column alphabetically, you could use:

```
 T1 // Prepend[Sort@Rest@#, #[[1]]] &
```

Which sorts all columns except the column headers and then reinserts them.

**Update**

To answer the question what does `allnames /. Rule @@@ Rest@T2` do. Firstly, `f@a` is just short for `f[a]`, so `Rest@T2` gives you all elements in T2 except the first, which was the headers. `Rule@@@{{a,2},{b,3}}` will replace the heads at level one with Rule, this means you get back `{Rule[a,2],Rule[b,3]}` or in shorthand `{a->2,b->3}`. So all in all what it says is: Take every element except the first of T2, and make them into rules, then use those rules to substitute the elements of allnames. This is why names that don't appear in T2 will remain the name.

As an added note, if you wanted to do this for an arbitrary list of tables like T1 and T2, you could write:

```
 {allnames, 
   Sequence @@ (allnames /. Rule @@@ Rest@# & /@ {T1, T2(*,etc*)})
 } // Transpose // Prepend[#, {"Name", "Advice BC", "Friend BC"}] & // Grid
```

Here I'm using the shorthand `@@` for apply to take a list of results and turning them into a sequence, and mapping the function I repeated twice before over a list of the tables I want to apply them to.

**Update 2**

To remove any entries that aren't replaced, we simply insert `/._String->Null` in the appropriate place.

```
 tablesList={T1, T2(*,etc*)};
 allnames = Union @@ (#[[2 ;;, 1]] & /@ tablesList);
 {allnames, 
 Sequence @@ ((allnames /. Rule @@@ Rest@# & /@ tablesList) /. _String -> Null)}
 // Transpose // Prepend[#, {"Name", "Advice BC", "Friend BC"}] & // Grid
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. Works perfectly.

To scale up (merging many tables), I figure I just update the allnames Union with a third,fourth, fifth etc. term, then add another term of ", allnames /. Rule @@@ Rest@T3" etc.

I get the Union, Transpose and Prepend parts of the code, but what oes"allnames /. Rule @@@ Rest@T3" actually do (I'm not good with using so many shortcuts)? Can you explain in words in a sentence that code?

Comment: @CameronMurray I added a short description of the syntax, as well as an example of using it with an arbitrary number of tables. I would suggest you read the help file on the shorthanda you don't understand `@@@`,`/.` etc. They are shorthands for extremely usefull functions in Mathematica and the help file is a good introduction to their usage.

Comment: jVincent.  How do you add the _String->NULL rule for missing values?

Comment: @CameronMurray I added that part as well. It needs to go after all the insertion rules have been applied.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use case for `JoinAcross`, since what you seem to want is exactly an `"Outer"` join (matching the concept from SQL).

Let's define some variables to work with:

```
friend = {
   {"Name", "Friend BC"}, 
   {"Bru-2", 25.1333}, 
   {"Al-1", 34.5667}, 
   {"Dave-4", 0.}, 
   {"Hal-8", 1.33333}, 
   {"Leo-12", 7.06667}, 
   {"Pat-16", 1.33333}, 
   {"Ned-14", 1.18333}, 
   {"Chas-3", 4.83333}, 
   (* {"Sam-19", 1.18333}, removed per comment *) 
   {"Ed-5", 61.6667}, 
   {"Ian-9", 4.2}, 
   {"Ken-11", 1.7}, 
   {"Quinn-17", 0.733333}, 
   {"Unwin-21", 0.733333}, 
   {"Frank-6", 33.1333}, 
   {"Gra-7", 0.}, 
   {"Jo-10", 44.2833}, 
   {"Tom-20", 0.}, 
   {"Mal-13", 0.}, 
   {"Ollie-15", 35.9167}};

advice = {
   {"Name", "Advice BC"},
   {"Sam-19", 0.},
   {"Mal-13", 0.},
   {"Leo-12", 0.},
   {"Ian-9", 0.},
   {"Pat-16", 0.},
   {"Dave-4", 0.},
   {"Tom-20", 0.0769231}, {"Quinn-17", 0.0769231},
   {"Ned-14", 0.0769231},
   {"Ken-11", 0.0769231},
   {"Jo-10", 0.0769231},
   {"Gra-7", 0.0769231},
   {"Frank-6", 0.0769231}, {"Unwin-21", 0.0769231},
   {"Ron-18", 0.0769231},
   {"Hal-8", 0.0769231},
   {"Bru-2", 0.0769231},
   {"Al-1", 5.74359},
   {"Ed-5", 38.5},
   {"Chas-3", 38.5},
   {"Ollie-15", 70.4103}};
```

In order to use `JoinAcross`, we'll first need a function to convert this sort of list with headings to an `Association`:

```
ClearAll[toAssociations];
toAssociations[({headings_List, rows___List})?MatrixQ] :=
 Map[
  AssociationThread[headings, #] &,
  {rows}]
```

The complicated pattern match is to avoid cases where the rows are missing elements, or when there is an empty list with no heading at all.

We might as well develop a function to generate tables from lists of `Association` while we're at it. This function is a little more general than we'll need, allowing the keys of each `Association` to be different and come in a different order.

```
ClearAll[fromAssociations];
fromAssociations[assocs : {___Association}] :=
 With[{
   keys =
    DeleteDuplicates@Catenate[Keys /@ assocs]
   },
  Prepend[
   Lookup[assocs, keys],
   keys]]
```

Then we have a one-liner to get the result. I leave the `Missing["Unmatched"]` elements in place instead of replacing them with `NULL` because that's much more idiomatic, but the replacement is easy.

```
fromAssociations@JoinAcross[
  toAssociations[advice],
  toAssociations[friend],
  "Name", "Outer"]
(*
{{"Name", "Advice BC", "Friend BC"}, 
 {"Bru-2", 0.0769231, 25.1333}, 
 {"Al-1", 5.74359, 34.5667}, 
 {"Dave-4", 0., 0.}, 
 {"Hal-8", 0.0769231, 1.33333}, 
 {"Leo-12", 0., 7.06667}, 
 {"Pat-16", 0., 1.33333}, 
 {"Ned-14", 0.0769231, 1.18333}, 
 {"Chas-3", 38.5, 4.83333}, 
 {"Ed-5", 38.5, 61.6667}, 
 {"Ian-9", 0., 4.2}, 
 {"Ken-11", 0.0769231, 1.7}, 
 {"Quinn-17", 0.0769231, 0.733333}, 
 {"Unwin-21", 0.0769231, 0.733333}, 
 {"Frank-6", 0.0769231, 33.1333}, 
 {"Gra-7",  0.0769231, 0.}, 
 {"Jo-10", 0.0769231, 44.2833}, 
 {"Tom-20", 0.0769231, 0.}, 
 {"Mal-13", 0., 0.}, 
 {"Ollie-15", 70.4103, 35.9167}, 
 {"Sam-19", 0., Missing["Unmatched"]}, 
 {"Ron-18", 0.0769231, Missing["Unmatched"]}}
*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SelectEquivalents defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6245166/884752) and pure functions this is how you could do it.

A bit hard maybe for a beginner, but very powerful.

```
SelectEquivalents[{l1,l2},
MapLevel->2,TagElement->First,TransformElement->Rest,
TransformResults->(Join[{#1},Flatten@#2]&),
FinalFunction->((PadRight[#, 3, NULL] & /@ # // SortBy[#, First] & ) &)
]
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the general case. For example if you make the argument `{l2,l1}` the output for `Ron-18` remains the same. If you make the argument `{l1,l2,l1,l2}` you get two element padding at the end of the `Ron-18` entry rather than alternating inserted "padding" `{Ron-18, 0.0769231, NULL,0.0769231, NULL}`. It seems this function is best for cases in which all list arguments have identical tagged elements (??)